expl3 and functional return value issue
I'm trying to perform 2 tasks to a string, first replace the letter "e" with a red highlighted "ie". The second is to remove the last 2 letters. I tried to achieve this through 2 functions, however the end result is that I got literally "p\boldhighlight {ie}ns" on the screen as if "\boldhighlight" is treated as regular strings. What am I doing wrong here?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for coloring text

\definecolor{highlightcolor}{HTML}{BA0000}

\newcommand{\boldhighlight}[1] {\textbf{\textcolor{highlightcolor}{#1}}}

\prgNewFunction \replaceString { mmm } {
    \tlSet \lInput {#1}
    \tlVarReplaceOnce {\lInput} {#2} {#3}
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lInput}
}

\prgNewFunction \removeLast { mm } {
    \tlSet \lTmpaTl {#1}

    \tlSet \lCharCount {\strVarCount \lTmpaTl}
    \intNew \lToRemove
    \intSet \lToRemove {#2}

    \tlSet \lResult {}

    \boolSetFalse \lReached
    \intNew \lI
    \intSet \lI {0}
    \boolVarDoUntil \lReached {
        \intIncr \lI
        \tlPutRight \lResult {\strItem {\expValue \lTmpaTl} {\lI}}
        \intCompareT {\lI} = {\lCharCount - \lToRemove} {\boolSetTrue \lReached}
    }
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lResult}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Function to rescan the token list
\prgNewFunction \RescanTokens { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \lTmpdTl {#1} % Store the input in a token list
    \tl_rescan:nn { } { \lTmpdTl } % Rescan the token list, executing commands
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tlSet \lTmpbTl {\replaceString {pensar} {e} {\boldhighlight{ie}}}
\tlSet \lTmpcTl {\removeLast{\expValue \lTmpbTl} {2}}

\message{tmpb***\lTmpbTl***}
\message{tmpc***\lTmpcTl***}

\lTmpbTl

\lTmpcTl

\RescanTokens{\lTmpcTl}

\end{document}


The code in the question introduces some unwanted spaces (see What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)). This can for example be seen if \documentclass{article} is replaced by \documentclass{standalone}. The result is below.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{functional}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for coloring text

\definecolor{highlightcolor}{HTML}{BA0000}

\newcommand{\boldhighlight}[1] {\textbf{\textcolor{highlightcolor}{#1}}}

\prgNewFunction \replaceString { mmm } {
    \tlSet \lInput {#1}
    \tlVarReplaceOnce {\lInput} {#2} {#3}
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lInput}
}

\prgNewFunction \removeLast { mm } {
    \tlSet \lTmpaTl {#1}

    \tlSet \lCharCount {\strVarCount \lTmpaTl}
    \intNew \lToRemove
    \intSet \lToRemove {#2}

    \tlSet \lResult {}

    \boolSetFalse \lReached
    \intNew \lI
    \intSet \lI {0}
    \boolVarDoUntil \lReached {
        \intIncr \lI
        \tlPutRight \lResult {\strItem {\expValue \lTmpaTl} {\lI}}
        \intCompareT {\lI} = {\lCharCount - \lToRemove} {\boolSetTrue \lReached}
    }
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lResult}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Function to rescan the token list
\prgNewFunction \RescanTokens { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \lTmpdTl {#1} % Store the input in a token list
    \tl_rescan:nn { } { \lTmpdTl } % Rescan the token list, executing commands
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tlSet \lTmpbTl {\replaceString {pensar} {e} {\boldhighlight{ie}}}
\tlSet \lTmpcTl {\removeLast{\expValue \lTmpbTl} {2}}

\message{tmpb***\lTmpbTl***}
\message{tmpc***\lTmpcTl***}

\lTmpbTl

\lTmpcTl

\RescanTokens{\lTmpcTl}

\end{document}


Therefore, the manual of the package functional mentions to put function definitions inside \IgnoreSpacesOn and \IgnoreSpacesOff. Also some % are added at the end of lines after \begin{document}. Moreover, the line \usepackage{expl3} is unnecessary. The lines with \message are removed. The result is below. Note that the spaces in the beginning are now removed.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{functional}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for coloring text

\definecolor{highlightcolor}{HTML}{BA0000}

\newcommand{\boldhighlight}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{highlightcolor}{#1}}}
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\prgNewFunction \replaceString { mmm } {
    \tlSet \lInput {#1}
    \tlVarReplaceOnce {\lInput} {#2} {#3}
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lInput}
}

\prgNewFunction \removeLast { mm } {
    \tlSet \lTmpaTl {#1}

    \tlSet \lCharCount {\strVarCount \lTmpaTl}
    \intNew \lToRemove
    \intSet \lToRemove {#2}

    \tlSet \lResult {}

    \boolSetFalse \lReached
    \intNew \lI
    \intSet \lI {0}
    \boolVarDoUntil \lReached {
        \intIncr \lI
        \tlPutRight \lResult {\strItem {\expValue \lTmpaTl} {\lI}}
        \intCompareT {\lI} = {\lCharCount - \lToRemove} {\boolSetTrue \lReached}
    }
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lResult}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Function to rescan the token list
\prgNewFunction \RescanTokens { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \lTmpdTl {#1} % Store the input in a token list
    \tl_rescan:nn { } { \lTmpdTl } % Rescan the token list, executing commands
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tlSet \lTmpbTl {\replaceString {pensar} {e} {\boldhighlight{ie}}}%
\tlSet \lTmpcTl {\removeLast{\expValue \lTmpbTl} {2}}%

\lTmpbTl

\lTmpcTl

\RescanTokens{\lTmpcTl}

\end{document}


The variables \lInput, \lCharCount and \lResult were not initialized. Below, this is done with \tlNew. Similarly for \lReached.
The braces in \tlVarReplaceOnce {\lInput} should be removed.
The code \intNew \lToRemove and \intNew \lI is placed inside the function \removeLast. Thus these integers will be defined each time that \removeLast is used. However, these should only be defined once. For example, if \tlSet \lTmpiTl {\removeLast{\expValue \lTmpbTl} {2}}% is used after the line with \tlSet \lTmpcTl then errors are given. Therefore, \intNew \lToRemove and \intNew \lI are placed outside the function \removeLast.
These changes are implemented in the code below. Also, \wlog{\lResult} is added after the line with \tlPutRight.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{functional}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for coloring text

\definecolor{highlightcolor}{HTML}{BA0000}

\newcommand{\boldhighlight}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{highlightcolor}{#1}}}
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\tlNew \lInput
\prgNewFunction \replaceString { mmm } {
    \tlSet \lInput {#1}
    \tlVarReplaceOnce \lInput {#2} {#3}
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lInput}
}
\tlNew \lCharCount
\tlNew \lResult
\intNew \lToRemove
\intNew \lI
\boolNew \lReached
\prgNewFunction \removeLast { mm } {
    \tlSet \lTmpaTl {#1}

    \tlSet \lCharCount {\strVarCount \lTmpaTl}
    \intSet \lToRemove {#2}

    \tlSet \lResult {}

    \boolSetFalse \lReached
    \intSet \lI {0}
    \boolVarDoUntil \lReached {
        \intIncr \lI
        \tlPutRight \lResult {\strItem {\expValue \lTmpaTl} {\lI}}
        \wlog{\lResult}
        \intCompareT {\lI} = {\lCharCount - \lToRemove} {\boolSetTrue \lReached}
    }
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lResult}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Function to rescan the token list
\prgNewFunction \RescanTokens { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \lTmpdTl {#1} % Store the input in a token list
    \tl_rescan:nn { } { \lTmpdTl } % Rescan the token list, executing commands
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tlSet \lTmpbTl {\replaceString {pensar} {e} {\boldhighlight{ie}}}%
\tlSet \lTmpcTl {\removeLast{\expValue \lTmpbTl} {2}}%

\lTmpbTl

\lTmpcTl

\RescanTokens{\lTmpcTl}

\end{document}

Then, the .log file contains
p
p\
p\b
p\bo
p\bol
p\bold
p\boldh
p\boldhi
p\boldhig
p\boldhigh
p\boldhighl
p\boldhighli
p\boldhighlig
p\boldhighligh
p\boldhighlight
p\boldhighlight 
p\boldhighlight {
p\boldhighlight {i
p\boldhighlight {ie
p\boldhighlight {ie}
p\boldhighlight {ie}n
p\boldhighlight {ie}ns

Thus each character is treated separately. This is due to the command \strItem. In the code below, \strItem is replaced by \tlItem and subsequently, \strVarCount by \tlVarCount. Also, \wlog{\lResult} is removed.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{functional}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for coloring text

\definecolor{highlightcolor}{HTML}{BA0000}

\newcommand{\boldhighlight}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{highlightcolor}{#1}}}
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\tlNew \lInput
\prgNewFunction \replaceString { mmm } {
    \tlSet \lInput {#1}
    \tlVarReplaceOnce \lInput {#2} {#3}
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lInput}
}
\tlNew \lCharCount
\tlNew \lResult
\intNew \lToRemove
\intNew \lI
\boolNew \lReached
\prgNewFunction \removeLast { mm } {
    \tlSet \lTmpaTl {#1}

    \tlSet \lCharCount {\tlVarCount \lTmpaTl}
    \intSet \lToRemove {#2}

    \tlSet \lResult {}

    \boolSetFalse \lReached
    \intSet \lI {0}
    \boolVarDoUntil \lReached {
        \intIncr \lI
        \tlPutRight \lResult {\tlItem {\expValue \lTmpaTl} {\lI}}
        \intCompareT {\lI} = {\lCharCount - \lToRemove} {\boolSetTrue \lReached}
    }
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lResult}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Function to rescan the token list
\prgNewFunction \RescanTokens { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \lTmpdTl {#1} % Store the input in a token list
    \tl_rescan:nn { } { \lTmpdTl } % Rescan the token list, executing commands
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tlSet \lTmpbTl {\replaceString {pensar} {e} {\boldhighlight{ie}}}%
\tlSet \lTmpcTl {\removeLast{\expValue \lTmpbTl} {2}}%

\lTmpbTl

\lTmpcTl

\RescanTokens{\lTmpcTl}

\end{document}


In the code below, \testA is defined with \edef. The aim is to replace e by i in pensar. It would be convenient if \testA would simply be pinsar. However, \meaning\testA still gives \replaceString{pensar}{e}{i}.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{functional}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for coloring text

\definecolor{highlightcolor}{HTML}{BA0000}

\newcommand{\boldhighlight}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{highlightcolor}{#1}}}
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\tlNew \lInput
\prgNewFunction \replaceString { mmm } {
    \tlSet \lInput {#1}
    \tlVarReplaceOnce \lInput {#2} {#3}
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lInput}
}
\tlNew \lCharCount
\tlNew \lResult
\intNew \lToRemove
\intNew \lI
\boolNew \lReached
\prgNewFunction \removeLast { mm } {
    \tlSet \lTmpaTl {#1}

    \tlSet \lCharCount {\tlVarCount \lTmpaTl}
    \intSet \lToRemove {#2}

    \tlSet \lResult {}

    \boolSetFalse \lReached
    \intSet \lI {0}
    \boolVarDoUntil \lReached {
        \intIncr \lI
        \tlPutRight \lResult {\tlItem {\expValue \lTmpaTl} {\lI}}
        \intCompareT {\lI} = {\lCharCount - \lToRemove} {\boolSetTrue \lReached}
    }
    \prgReturn {\expValue \lResult}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\begin{document}
\edef\testA{\replaceString{pensar}{e}{i}}
\texttt{\meaning\testA}
\end{document}


This problem is solved in the code below. The package functional is not used anymore. Instead, expl3 is used. The command \replaceString uses \str_map_tokens:nn. The command \removeLast uses \str_range:nnn.
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{highlightcolor}{HTML}{BA0000}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \boldhighlight { m }
  { \textbf { \textcolor { highlightcolor } {#1} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__luyi_replace_aux:nnn #1#2#3
  { \str_if_eq:nnTF {#3} {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \replaceString { mmm }
  { \str_map_tokens:nn {#1} { \__luyi_replace_aux:nnn {#2} {#3} } }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \removeLast { mm }
  { \str_range:nnn {#1} { 1 } { - 1 - ( #2 ) } }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \removeandreplace { mmmm }
  { \exp_args:Ne \replaceString { \removeLast {#1} {#2} } {#3} {#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\edef\testA{\replaceString{pensar}{e}{i}}
\verb|\testA|\\
\testA\\
\texttt{\meaning\testA}\\
\edef\testB{\replaceString{pensar}{e}{\noexpand\boldhighlight{ie}}}
\verb|\testB|\\
\testB\\
\texttt{\meaning\testB}\\
\edef\testC{\removeLast{pensar}{2}}
\verb|\testC|\\
\testC\\
\texttt{\meaning\testC}\\
\edef\testD{\removeandreplace{pensar}{2}{e}{\noexpand\boldhighlight{ie}}}
\verb|\testD|\\
\testD\\
\texttt{\meaning\testD}
\end{document}



oh, sorry. I missed you were doing this in standalone. will delete.
